# SQL select query for Days count from Registration Date

Tags: sql-server

SQL select query for days count from registration date. I have a column RegistrationDate in my `Registration` table in my SQL Server 2008 database.

Suppose I have a `registrationDate` like this:

```
2016-12-10
```

and suppose today is `2016-12-20`, then the output should be like:

```
registrationDate     registrationAge     
  2016-12-10             10 days
```

Comment: I am new in sql query, please can update your answer. @GurwinderSingh

Comment: try SELECT DATEDIFF (dd, column1, column2) FROM MyTable

Comment: @MMK updated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`datediff`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx):

```
select registrationDate,
  datediff(day, cast(registrationDate as date), getdate()) + ' days' as registrationAge 
from table
```

Comment: you added +'days' giving, if i will remove days means giving days count, can you check, error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'days' to data type int. @Gurwinder Singh

Comment: Just lose the + ' days' part if you just want integer value

Comment: No I need that part also. @Gurwinder Singh